# Conditional Formatting Google Sheets cells when in-cell formula is false

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am wondering if there is a way to do conditional formatting in the "else" portion of an if statement. For example, right now I have:

```
=if(MONTH(today())=2, (M2 * Y2), (*turn cell green*))
```

I can't seem to find a way to do this with conditional formatting (I can only seem to find a way to turn the cell green if a certain event occurs). If I just try to turn the cell green if the month of today is not 2, it will turn green, however the cell text is "FALSE." I would like to turn the cell green but also keep the cell text.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to color the cell when the current month is February (2)?

Highlight the cell and add the following as custom formula:

```
=if(month(today())<>2,true)
```

Note that the formula of a cell is independent of the conditional formatting. So your turn cell green goes into conditional formatting. The M2*Y2 part goes into the cell :)

Comment: Thank you!! I figured out how to get to here : '=$A2<>text(MONTH(today())&"-1","MMMM")'. In A2, I have "February". However, google sheets doesn't think that these are equal, because the cell is changing color. Is there a way to compare two strings that I am missing?

Comment: In a dummy sheet I tried your function and it is working. If the cell has the value "February" it is not turned green. Otherwise it is always green. Maybe you have an issue with the cell. If your just want to reference one cell use $A$2 to peg both the column and the row. Otherwise the 2 is a relative reference and changes depending on where you apply the conditional formatting. [Check this example.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rvz7SUa74M0xoDL4KgiKpnR4cf_s-FddHrgSd03E05U/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi Ethan, can you please accept my answer and upvote it, if I helped to solve your problem.